# How to enlarge the small screen of the remote computer in AnyDesk?

Tags: display, resolution, anydesk

When I connect to a remote computer with *AnyDesk*, I see the screen of the other computer in a small window on my computer.

I want the remote computer screen to completely fill the window of the AnyDesk program (**not Full Screen mode**). Selecting *Stretch* in the settings distorts the resolution. I can get the best image with *Shrink*, but in this case I see a small screen.

How can I set the remote computer screen in high resolution so that it completely fills the AnyDesk window?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lHbS.png)

Comment: Your screen/window will match the resolution of the target. The idea is usually to see what they see so? So probably not?

Comment: @NickSlash Yes, the purpose is fulfilled, I see what the other side sees. There is no problem with that. However, if you look at the image I attached, there are gaps on all four sides of the screen, I want them to disappear.

Comment: You can use stretch instead of shrink to fill your display and remove the bars at expense of quality. I think it's effectively a live video of the target so unless you can change the resolution at the target you won't be able to increase the resolution at your end.

Comment: Thank you, but I explained above that I had already tried the things you suggested and could not get any results, so I was looking for "another" solution.